# oracle 11g Enterprise databse SID error ORA-12505

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have installed oracle Enterprice 11g database (Desktop mode). it was working fine, once I have stopped my database using sqlplus  connected as=> **conn sys@orcl as sysdba** and used **shutdown immediate** now when I am starting it it is not connection to SID below is screen shot

[image]

Even I used **Startup** button on **Enterprise Manager**

and when I try to connect using **sqlplus / as SYSDBA** it says **ora-01031-insufficient privileges**

**Error Log**

> Fatal NI connect error 12505, connecting to: 
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=D:\app\Ravi_Bhushan\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\emagent.exe)(HOST=RAVIBHUSHAN-PC)(USER=SYSTEM))))
>
> VERSION INFORMATION:    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 -
>   Production    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows:
>   Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production   Time: 12-NOV-2013 15:14:32   Tracing
>   not turned on.   Tns error struct:
>       ns main err code: 12564
>       TNS-12564: TNS:connection refused
>       ns secondary err code: 0
>       nt main err code: 0
>       nt secondary err code: 0
>       nt OS err code: 0

Comment: hv u tried restarting oracle service?

Comment: yes, so many times :(

Comment: can u find error log?

Comment: **SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Nov 12 16:11:56 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> SQL> ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  778387456 bytes
Fixed Size      1374808 bytes
Variable Size    318768552 bytes
Database Buffers   452984832 bytes
Redo Buffers      5259264 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options**

Comment: I have modified my question, error log is also mentioned now.

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/642253?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

1. Open ***Net Manager***. In ***Oracle Net Configuration***, open ***Local***, and then, open ***Listeners***.
2. Select your Listener.
3. In the upper right ComboBox, select ***Database Services***.
4. Clic ***Add Database***.
5. Fill the 3 fields: ***Global Database Name*** (i.e. ORCL.NET. In SQL Plus type SELECT * FROM GLOBAL_NAME), ***Oracle Home Directory*** (i.e. C:\app\User\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1) and ***SID*** (i.e. orcl)
6. File > Save Network Configuration.
7. Restart the ***OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener*** service.